# Apex Editor for supporting format for code

Tags: eclipse-plugin, salesforce, apex-code

There is sales force developer console for write apex code ....

There is force.IDE that is eclipse plug-in but, that does not support auto-correct, and code formatting facilities.

So there is any other Editor is available for developing apex code which support format code and suggest attribute context-menu...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this myself, but many people at Dreamforce last year were talking about using Sublimetext:

http://www.sublimetext.com/

in combination with a Mavensmate plug-in:

http://mavensmate.com/

to work with their Salesforce code. I know it has re-indentation and auto-complete.  I don't know about auto-correct.